# Could not load type 'Xamarin.Forms.Internals.NameScope' from assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core, Version=2.0

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Getting this with a Xamarin Forms project, but only when running the Android project.

Could not load type 'Xamarin.Forms.Internals.NameScope' from assembly 'Xamarin.Forms.Core, Version=2.0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Close your Xamarin studio.
- Delete all `\bin` and `\obj` folders of corresponding project.
- Restart the Xamarin studio.

---

> *It will be better of you edit your question and add your full Exception, other that it's first few lines.*